# How to display total time per build target in Phing output

Tags: php, phing

In my `build.xml` I have a main build target which is composed of several targets.
I need to check how much time takes to run those targets.
Currently in my output console, I only see `TOTAL TIME` for the build.
Is there a way to show times for internal targets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite straight forward.

1. Create your logger class which extends phings `DefaultLogger`
2. Use event listener method `targetStarted` to store start timestamp
3. Use event listener method `targetFinished` to calculate elapsed time and print it to output stream
4. Use the logger by using command line attribute `-logger`
   f.e. to use `lib/loggers/MyLogger.php` call: `phing -logger lib.loggers.MyLogger`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print execution times of subtargets just use:

```
$phing <target> -logger phing.listener.TargetLogger
```